# BST Tree, Search function is giving odd times (measuring of search function)

Tags: rust, binary-search-tree

I am trying to measure the time my BST search func takes to search an element in a 100-10,000 elements BST, with sorted & unsorted values.

Link to playground:
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d6708d951f80d58cdb77bc5fac1fc514

but I am getting weird results (in nanoseconds)

```
for 100 items: 
BST - sorted: 33ns
BST - unsorted: 46ns

for 1,000 items:
BST - sorted: 10ns
BST - unsorted: 6ns
```

Seems impossible that the array is 10x times bigger and the time it took was way faster.

BST Search function:

```
 pub fn search(&mut self, val: i32) -> bool {
        if val == self.value {
            true
        } else {
            if val <= self.value {
                match self.left {
                    None => false,
                    Some(ref mut node) => node.search(val),
                }
            } else {
                match self.right {
                    None => false,
                    Some(ref mut node) => node.search(val),
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

BST Insert function:

```
pub fn insert(&mut self, val: i32) {
        if val <= self.value {
            match self.left {
                None => {
                    self.left = Some(Box::new(BSTNode {
                        value: val,
                        left: None,
                        right: None,
                    }))
                }
                Some(ref mut node) => node.insert(val),
            }
        } else {
            match self.right {
                None => {
                    self.right = Some(Box::new(BSTNode {
                        value: val,
                        left: None,
                        right: None,
                    }))
                }
                Some(ref mut node) => node.insert(val),
            }
        }
    }
```

Timing function:

```
pub fn bst_search_timing(original_arr: &mut Vec<i32>) -> u128 {
    let copy_arr: Vec<i32> = original_arr.to_vec();
    let mut bst = BSTNode::new(1);
    for item in copy_arr {
        bst.insert(item);
    }
    let now = Instant::now();
    bst.search(rand::random::<i32>());
    let elapsed = now.elapsed();
    return elapsed.as_nanos();
}
```

Main.rs:

```
let mut step = 100;
    let times = 100;
    let max = 10000;
    while step <= max {
        let mut bst_search_sum = 0;
        let mut bst_search_unsorted_sum = 0;

        let mut sorted_arr: Vec<i32> = vec![];
        for x in 0..step {
            sorted_arr.push(x);
        }
        for _ in 0..times {
            let mut unsorted_arr: Vec<i32> = sorted_arr.to_vec();
            unsorted_arr.shuffle(&mut thread_rng());

            bst_search_sum += timing::bst_search_timing(&mut sorted_arr);
            bst_search_unsorted_sum += timing::avl_search_timing(&mut sorted_arr);
}
```

And then I print the average:

```
println!(
            "Average for {} elements: {}ns - BST_SEARCH: SORTED ARR",
            step,
            bst_search_sum / times
        );
 println!(
            "Average for {} elements: {}ns - BST_SEARCH: UNSORTED ARR",
            step,
            bst_search_unsorted_sum / times
        );
```

Comment: Can you provide the `insert` function?

Comment: @trincot provided, also I've added a link to rust-playground to run my code, which makes my code run in legit results, so the problem does not occur in playground for some odd reason

Comment: I think the main issue is that you search only one value per timing. You'll get more reliable results if you would time a simple loop that searches 1000 values.

Comment: @trincot I tried that as well, but got pretty much the same values

Comment: Really? 1000 searches take as much time as 1 search?

Comment: @trincot yeah, it took like a bit more and I’m taking about something like 5ns more or something.. so it is very odd.

Comment: Then increase the number of searches until you see a noticeable difference and it becomes significant.

Comment: @trincot how it’s possible that In playground I’m getting normal timing results tho?

Comment: I would expect that a local environment will run your code **much** faster than a virtualised server on which the CPUs are shared.

Comment: @trincot I see, that makes sense